# Cannot make skype calls (win 10 machine)

Tags: windows-10, skype

I have skype installed on a few devices, and on one of them, a Lenovo with Windows 10 Pro installed, it is impossible to make and receive skype calls. When I call, it simply doesn't ring on the other side and tells me the user is busy, and when others call, skype would not even notify me.

This problem is similar to what I had on other devices when I used to be logged in on the cell phone. In that case, if someone called me, I wouldn't be able to press the answering buttons. This problem affected all my computers. I solved it by logging out of the phone skype.

But, this particular machine is stubborn - I have another windows 10 computer on which skype works just fine. I tried what was suggested on microsoft forums - `/remotelogout`, but didn't have any effect.

I also thought the proxy must be the problem, as this computer uses a proxy server at work. But, skype is set on the no proxy option, plus the linux skype works fine with the proxy on.

So, I'm not sure where to look for a solution, especially because I can't see what makes my two Lenovo machines with win 10 different when it comes to skype.

Edit: after reinstalling skype and restarting the machine, in a true win fashion, the skype works.

Comment: Is it the standalone application for Skype or the Skype app?

Comment: I think it's the skype I installed (so standalone) but, just in case I'm wrong, I'm uninstalling it and re-installing. I actually still have the installer in my downloads directory.

Comment: If it's in your download directory it's the standalone version as the Skype app will only install via the Windows Store and therefor wouldn't show up in your download folder.
Try the app to see if that resolve it. Otherwise it might be a problem with the proxy.

Comment: Now skype test call doesn't work, either.